# How to have my dev database mirror my production database in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, dev-to-production

I am looking to have an exact copy of my production database to be used in dev for testing. What I would prefer is if changes are made in production they will be mirrored in dev but if changes are made in dev they are only changed in dev. I was looking into Cluster to Cluster Sync but I am not sure if that is what I exactly need because when I looked into the use cases for it it doesn't mention anything of the sort. Can anyone let me know if there are other avenues I should be looking into? Thanks!